# How to execute a python file from php

Tags: php, python, server

i want to execute a python script on my server which execute and return a list of data.
How can i execute python script by php and return back the python list data in php code.

for example.
python_file.py

```
import os


def list_data():
    """
    this function will return a content list of path directory
    :return: 
    """
    path = 'C:/'
    my_list = os.listdir(path)
    return my_list

print list_data()
```

Comment: Could you edit question and show us what you have so far for your php code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
<?php
    $data_list = `python path/to/python_file.py`;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `exec` command you can execute a shell command.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

So basically any script ( including python ) can be executed.

But using `exec` is not encouraged in web apps. It basically lets you run shell commands and execute them on the server. Most shared hosts come with it disabled.